# Xamarin forms, scrollview doesn't scroll into a StackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have this:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <LineEntry />
   <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      <StackLayout x:Name="stack" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
      </StackLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```

But it does not scroll, except if you are into the LineEntry, because the keyboard is up. I think it's because the content page has less height than the scrollView, but don't know how to fix this.

I will update some mockups(can't use the real images) for more information, in the first one, does not works, in the second one, it works:

[image: Scroll doesn't works]
[image: Scroll Works]

Comment: Set some background colors to the ScrollView & StackLayouts and you'll see their heights.

Comment: i did, will edit with some images to help, ty

Answer (score 0):

> the content page has less height than the scrollView

This should be the first reason , and the send reason is the Content should exists some things , not a empty layot in `ScrollView` :

The follow code can work , just for reference :

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Entry Text="First Entry"/>
    <ScrollView HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Beige" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
        <StackLayout x:Name="stack"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        HeightRequest="200">
            <Entry Placeholder="Second Entry"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```